# A little trouble with PHP

Tags: php, sql

This might be a very simple answer but my brain is absolutely fried. The code I have in place doesn't display like I want it to.  My question is, how would I get the following codes to display properly?

For instance, this code

```
$toplinks = '<a href="profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username . '</a> &bull; 
    <a href="edit_profile.php">Edit info</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
```

Displays perfectly when I echo it out like this

```
<div id="header"><?php echo "$toplinks"; ?></div>
```

But this code doesn't display the same as the $toplinks

```
    echo '$toplinks= "<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
    <a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
```

This is the code I have in place as a whole

```
<?php
session_start();


$toplinks = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $toplinks = '<a href="profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username . '</a> &bull; 
    <a href="edit_profile.php">Edit info</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
} else {
    echo '$toplinks= "<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
    <a href="login.php">Log In</a>';

}
?>
```

And I try to echo these two out with this

```
<div id="header"><?php echo "$toplinks"; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $toplinks = '<a href="profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username . '</a> &bull; 
    <a href="edit_profile.php">Edit info</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; <a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '$toplinks= "<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
```

This code does not assign anything to `$toplinks`, as it is in a string. What you want to do is:

```
$toplinks= "<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>"
echo $toplinks
```

or simply:

```
echo "<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>"
```

Comment: I wanted to tell the difference between users who are logged in from the ones who arent. Would this code be able to tell the difference?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you don't need to use echo in "else" statement

try to replace

```
echo '$toplinks= "<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
```

with

```
$toplinks= '<a href="register.php">Register</a> &bull; 
<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
```

Comment: Because the else tells the difference between users who are not logged in